# Checking for different words in a value

Tags: openrefine, grel

I need to check for different keywords in different cells of a column called item_description. If the cell contains that word, 1 is returned. Otherwise 0 is returned

```
if(or(cells.item_description.value.contains("new"), cells.item_description.value.contains("5"), cells.item_description.value.contains("some")), "1", "0")
```

I expected it to return 1 or 0, but I got the error message:

> Parsing error at offset 95: Missing number, string, identifier, regex,
>   or parenthesized expression

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes probably from your mix of different quotation marks (" IS NOT “, even if both seem very close at first glance).

This version should work:

```
if(or(cells.item_description.value.contains("new"), cells.item_description.value.contains("5"), cells.item_description.value.contains("some")), "1", "0")
```

By the way, in OpenRefine 3 (and 3.1), `contains` now accept a regex. So you can rewrite your ifelse like this:

```
if(cells.item_description.value.contains(/new|5|some/), "1", "0")
```